# How to turn off explicit assembly reference from nuget /lib folder

Tags: c#, nuget

I have a need to deploy both a (C#) `Release` and `Debug` version of my assembly in the same package since that package has a dependency on a different managed CLI (C++) package that also has a `Release` and `Debug` version of it.

I am including a `*.targets` file to conditionally pick the desired assembly based on the Configuration in the consuming project. The problem I am having is that I cannot get `msbuild` to stop using the automatic `dll` reference logic it uses when it finds files under the `lib` folder.

According to the logs, it is detecting a "conflict" between the reference specified in the targets file and the automatic reference.

According to docs, if there is a `references` element defined in the `*.nuspec` file, the automatic logic is not fired off and only the items in the element are used. I *thought* that I could try using an empty `references` element but that just ends up being ignored during `nuget pack`.

Here is my `*.nuspec` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
   <metadata>
      <id>Shared.BondCalculator</id>
      <tags>longview shared native dotnet</tags>

      <dependencies>
         <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.8">
            ...
         </group>
         <group targetFramework="native0.0">
            ...
         </group>
      </dependencies>

      <references />
   </metadata>

   <files>
      <file src="bin\x64\Release\net48\Shared.BondCalculator.*" target="lib\net48\" />
      <file src="bin\x64\Debug\net48\Shared.BondCalculator.*" target="lib\net48\Debug\" />

      <file src="bin\x64\Release\net48\Shared.BondCalculator.*" target="build\native\x64\" />

      <file src="Shared.BondCalculator.native.targets" target="\build\native\Shared.BondCalculator.targets" />
      <file src="Shared.BondCalculator.dotnet.targets" target="\build\net48\Shared.BondCalculator.targets" />
   </files>
</package>
```

And here is the `Shared.BondCalculator.targets` file used for `net48`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

   <PropertyGroup>
      <BondCalculatorReference>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\lib\net48\</BondCalculatorReference>
      <BondCalculatorReference Condition=" $(Configuration) == 'Debug' ">$(BondCalculatorReference)Debug\</BondCalculatorReference>
      <BondCalculatorReference>$(BondCalculatorReference)Shared.BondCalculator.dll</BondCalculatorReference>
   </PropertyGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
      <Reference Include="$(BondCalculatorReference)" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
   </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Ultimately, the question comes down to how can I set up my package so that **only** the `<Reference>` defined in the `*.targets` file is used.

The only solution I can think of that I am fairly confident will work would be to ignore conventions and *not* use the `lib` folder. Put the assemblies in another folder (for example, `tools` (horrible choice)) which should cause the automatic referencing to be skipped. But this approach just seems like a hack.

Comment: why not maje two projects and deploy them

Comment: That was considered a possibility and rejected before I posted the question. While we can, for SDK based projects, conditionally load one or the other package, we cannot do that for the numerous `package.config` style projects we have.